# How to install flow types for @material-ui/core@v4.x.x

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, flowtype, flow-typed

How do I install the flow types for material-ui/core for 4.x.x? It appears there haven't been updates since 1.x.x https://github.com/flow-typed/flow-typed/blob/master/definitions/npm/%40material-ui/core_v1.x.x/flow_v0.58.x-v0.88.x/core_v1.x.x.js and the documentation is pretty sparse https://material-ui.com/guides/flow/. I thought this may not be support but the icon type definitions seem to be maintained here so I'm a little confused.

Answer (score -2):

```
npm install --save @types/material-ui
```

or

```
yarn add @types/material-ui
```

https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/material-ui